# Disable all buttons while transitioning - enable all buttons again afterwards

Tags: javascript, html, css

**EDITED THE ENTIRE QUESTION BECAUSE OF A LOT OF MISAPPREHENSION [11:11, 24-02-2019]**

First, when a button is pressed a transition will occur.

Now, I want to disable all buttons when a button is pressed and a transition occurs. The buttons should all be enabled again when the transition has finished.

Here is a video explaining my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/sebastian3495/o78jktcL/

Javascript: (There are two types of buttons)

```
$(".left-btn").click(() => {
    var current = $("section:nth-child(1)").css("margin-left");

    var new_value = (parseInt(current.replace(/px/,"")) + $("section")[1].offsetWidth) + "px";

    $("section:nth-child(1)").css("margin-left", new_value)
});

$(".right-btn").click(() => {
    var current = $("section:nth-child(1)").css("margin-left");

    var new_value = (parseInt(current.replace(/px/,"")) - $("section")[1].offsetWidth) + "px";

    console.log(current, new_value);

    $("section:nth-child(1)").css("margin-left", new_value)
});
```

**The problem**
As you can see here, https://gyazo.com/b4662038419865ba57e85ca29c3d8a8e, occurs because you are able to click any button again before the transition has finished, the cards gets misaligned.

**The cards are misligned when** the transition has finished and you can see a little of two different cards, like in this case: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN1U.png) This is the case I would like to avoid.

**Here is a complete fiddle. Play around with it; can you solve it?
https://jsfiddle.net/sebastian3495/y3nume0p/49/**

---

I recommend you change the JsFiddle view setting to the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt6ab.png)

Comment: Please post the most current fiddle on this site as a [mcve].

Comment: I did? Uhm ... I don't know what to say.

Comment: Go to the link and read. OP (***O**riginal **P**oster*, that's you) is required to post a [mcve] on this site. Links to a live demo do not count. The reason is because links brake and if and when they do, readers will only see a question with some half-baked code or no code at all. Let's take your code displayed in your post: `section:nth-child(1)` what significance is that selector to the reader without seeing the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the set timeout function that waits for two seconds for your transition to finish and re-enable the buttons as shown in the code below.

```
$("button").click(() => {
  $("left-btn").prop("disabled", true);
  $("right-btn").prop("disabled", true);

  setTimeout( () => {
    $("left-btn").prop("disabled", false);
    $("right-btn").prop("disabled", false);
  },2000);
});
```

This will disable all buttons on your page till the transition is done.

You may check the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/yw5vmt07/1/